# Upgrading from jdk1.6->1.7 on 10.9

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I am running 10.9, which came with 1.7 already installed.  Several months ago, I had to downgrade it to 1.6 now am trying to upgrade it back to 1.7 and now have a really messed up install.  I've installed the official 1.7 installer from Oracle but it doesn't fix the issue, with either maven or or java.  See output below:

```
> LM-BWI-00873340:jdk1.7.0_67.jdk user$ mvn -v Error: JAVA_HOME is not
> defined correctly.   We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java

> LM-BWI-00873340:jdk1.7.0_67.jdk user$ java -v Unrecognized option: -v
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal
> exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I think my sym links are all screwed up, I have followed various guides out there and now have one screwed up installation.

EDIT - my bash profile

```
LM-BWI-00873340:~ user$ cat .bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:
```

Comment: Set java home correctly

Comment: i have export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home" is in my ~/.bash_profile but it doesnt do anything

Comment: please share you path as well

Comment: do echo $PATH in terminal what does it give ?

Comment: you need to set your path variable as well in the .bash_profile file

Comment: do you mean $PATH? if so, i get this: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Yes you need to add java home to that ...

Comment: That end-of-the-world error is normal when you call `java -v`. The Java argument for version is, nonsensically, `java -version`.

Comment: If you're upgrading, you might as well go to Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the following lines to the .bash_profile
Make sure this line is after java_home is exported

```
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:
```

Comment: Still not working, please see my edit in my initial post for my .bash_profile.

Comment: your JAVA_HOME should be like this 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home

Comment: updated in original post, still the same error.  i think somewhere, i have a screwed up symlink

Comment: Are you sure about your java install directory ?
Mine is stored on /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/

Comment: my home folder is at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Contents/Home

Comment: thanks so much for the help! it finally works.  java -v doesn't but as long as maven works, im happy.